# How do you convert angle with velocity to x velocity and y velocity?

Tags: physics, angles, trajectory

This question can be simplified to:  If you lean a pencil of a certain length at a certain angle what is the x and y position of the tip?
So, basically, I am making a game that plots a balls path through the air as it travels.  I want the user to enter an angle and velocity to launch a ball at and get the program to convert that to an x and y velocity so that it can work out how to plot the balls movement across the screen.  The x velocity doesn't change through the simulation but the y velocity will decrease constantly until the ball touches the ground again.  This is why I referenced to a pencil because it relates to turtle graphics calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of [the Unit Circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle), multiplied by the length of the vector we want as output:

```
x = length * cos(angle)
y = length * sin(angle)
```