# How to calcolate moving vector of object by its rotation degress in 2d

Tags: 2d, movement, vector

i have object in game which is rotating when i move my joystick , now i need to   calculate its movement vector by its rotation
the object always moving forward and controlled by the joystick , the joystick is only setting its direction by degree .
here is the image which illustrate the scene .
i need some formula of the vector which the object will move .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert angle with velocity to x velocity and y velocity?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125296/how-do-you-convert-angle-with-velocity-to-x-velocity-and-y-velocity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter trigonometry!

To calculate the velocity vector of the ship, you need to use the following formula:

```
v.x := sin(angle) * velocity
v.y := cos(angle) * velocity
```

Also, if your angle is in degrees, you may need to convert it to radian:

```
angleInRadian := angle / 180 * pi
```